# Defining a file name in assembly language

Tags: file, assembly, nasm

I'm working on writing assembly code, I have defined a file name to be used within the code.. 
and it shown to me a syntax error that I couldn't find it. The problem is with defining the file name.
the below is the code

---

```
" section .data
file_name db ‘haneens_texts.txt’
msg db 'Even if you’re on the right track, you’ll get run over if you just sit there'
len edu $-msg "
```

---

Comment: Make sure you use proper ascii quotes not some unicode stuff.

Comment: Which text editor do you use?  The opening quote after `file_name db` is wrong.  Also, you seem to be missing a NUL terminator for the file name.

Comment: Also `section .data` needs to be on a line by itself, not `" section .data` with a stray double quote at the start of that line.  Same for after the `equ`.  Which you typoed as `eDu`